# Why is rawurlencode() in PHP adding additional escape characters to ampersands?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, urlencode

I think I'm missing something obvious here but it is driving me crazy and I can't figure it out.  I'm developing a WordPress plugin and part of it needs to take the WordPress post title and send that to a RESTful web service to do something else.  So of course I want to rawurlencode() the post title since who knows what text might be in there.  However, for some reason the output I'm getting has extra escape characters and I have no idea where they are coming from (and it's causing problems with the web service I'm calling obviously).

My code is fairly straight forward:

```
$topic = get_the_title($post_id);
$curl_post_fields = 'name=' . rawurlencode( $topic );
```

Yet when I print the output of those two strings I get:

```
topic=a & b
name=a%20%26%23038%3B%20b
```

Whereas I would expect the URL encoded string to be

```
name=a%20%26%20b
```

I have no idea where that extra %23038%3B could be coming from.  If I'm reading the encoding on that correctly it translates to #038; but I still don't know where it's coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a html encoding in between as well, instead of `&`, `&#038;` is in the encoded string. Probably because & has to be escaped in html, and the get_title function escapes this using `html_special_chars` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be happening but when I print the result of get_title_function() it's literally what I posted "a & b" - nothing escaped.  So the HTML encoding is coming from rawurlencode() - that's the only function I'm calling between the two echo statements whose output I put in the question.

Comment: Oh wait, you know what.  I just realized that is EXACTLY what is happening.  When I was printing it, it was being seen as text/html in my browser so I didn't look at the source and notice the escaping.  I can't believe I didn't catch this.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with that when i used an older php version

Comment: Yeah I'm on 5.3.3 but I googled to try to see if it was a known bug and I didn't see anything.  Plus I figure this plugin may need to run across various versions on shared hosting sites so I want to make it as compatible as possible.  If it's really a bug with rawurlencode() I'm surprised there wasn't a lot more turning up on Google and lots of people having this problem...